# How do I broadcast on all channels on different servers in XChat?

Tags: xchat

How do I send a message across all channels I'm in on different servers simultaneously?  I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to program XChat I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and xchat 2.8.8.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, xchat is not developped anymore. Better use hexchat